# Manual Http error response code in non-existent folder via routing

Tags: .htaccess, http, routes

I am getting unexpected behaviour when i try to manually send error response.
If my `.htaccess` is responsible for the error response , then appropriate error document is loaded and displayed , with according response code in browser console.

However , if my router is origin of the response code , then i get blank screen , but correct response code.

`.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|icon|zip|rar|png|jpg|gif|pdf)$ index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /err/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /err/500.html
```

part of my router that sends the response is the following

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
```

I also tried `HTTP/1.0`.
Furthermore i was thinking that maybe relative path to error page might be an issue , but discarded this idea after attempting to access a document that is forbidden via `.htaccess`

**EDIT**

I should also point out , this scenario happens when URL for not-existing article is requested. Is it possible that Server is looking for a `.htaccess` file in a folder based on URL ? Eg: `domain/blog/non-existent` , is server looking for `blog` folder ? I am specifically asking this because there is no `blog` folder

Answer (score 0):

try to put this code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.html
ErrorDocument 403 /err/403.html
ErrorDocument 500 /err/500.html
```

***before***

```
RewriteEngine On
```

and of course check that you clear cache or use another browser

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help